# Reprojecting with a specific value for no-data

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I'm using Python to perform forest analysis.
I used the [MSPA tool](https://forest.jrc.ec.europa.eu/en/activities/lpa/mspa/) to produce a fragmentation map of a specific AOI (for testing I use Singapore). To produce statistics that make sense in Ha I need to use a conform projection (ESRI:54009) but I want to go back to EPSG:4326 for display purposes.

Here is the unprojected fragmentation map in QGIS (as it's coming from an ESRI:54009, the projection is not a pure rectangle):

[image]

Then using Gdal Python binding I project this map into EPSG:4326:

```py
gdal.Warp(mspa_map_proj, mspa_map, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW'], dstSRS='EPSG:4326')
```

but I obtain the following image with grey bands on the left and right sides:
[image]

The problem is that the developer of the MSPA tool decided to use 0 as the non-forest value (in grey) and 129 for the background (in white).

So my question is simple : is it possible to force gdal to use the value 129 when it's adding pixels to complete the image when reprojecting instead of 0?

### Edit

here is the ESRI:54009 sample for those who want to test
http://www.filedropper.com/sn308111mspamaptmp

Comment: Is your image a paletted one or RGB?

Comment: It's a paletted image

Comment: And your aim is to mark that palette entry 129, that is white color in the palette, means nodata, right? Have you checked that gdalwarp creates a paletted output as well, and that it is using the same palette?

Comment: The second image is created by gdalwarp so yes it embeds the same color palette. My objective is to mark the created pixels as 129 instead of 0

Comment: Could you share a small test image?

Comment: I edited the Post with a filedropper link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a try with your image and gdalwarp

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 -co compress=LZW -dstNodata 129 SN_30_8_1_1_1_mspa_map_tmp.tif SN_warped.tif
```

Nodata is set correctly into 129 and I do not see grey triangles with QGIS

[image: Nodata set to palette color 129]

I can't say why your Python code does not seem to take the dstNodata into account.

Comment: maybe there were a typo the first time, or I mess up with my files but yes the new image I produced with both the gdal python binding and the CLI worked fine. I'll remove the note. Can you add the python binding method to your answer for anyone passing by ?